# SharpDX how to correct vertex positions after matrix rotation

Tags: c#, rotation, sharpdx

I am getting 2d coordinates from Vector3. I have to correct positions to get right results. Indeed it seems I get correct positions like this but I do not know how to correct position when rotated.

Here my worldViewMatrix that I do operations but those operations not passed to my VertexData then I try to correct positions.

```
WorldViewMatrix =  Matrix.Scaling(Scale) * Matrix.RotationX(Rotation.X) * Matrix.RotationY(Rotation.Y) * Matrix.RotationZ(Rotation.Z) * Matrix.Translation(Position.X, Position.Y, Position.Z) * viewProj;
```

I am trying to correct it like:

```
        public Vector2 Convert_3Dto2D(Vector3 position, Vector3 translation, Vector3 scale, Vector3 rotation, Matrix viewProj, RenderForm_EX form)
        {position += translation;


        position += translation;
        position = Vector3.Multiply(position, scale);
        //ROTATION ?

            var project = Vector3.Project(position, 0, 0, form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height, 0, 1, viewProj);

            Console.WriteLine(project.X+" "+ project.Y);
            return new Vector2(project.X, project.Y);
        }
```

What can I do to correct rotated position ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, post a little more information about "correct positions".  I will take a stab at this and assume you want to move your vertex into world space, then work out what pixel it occupies.

Usually you order multiplying your order by

Translate * Rotate * Scale;

if you want Viewprojection to apply correctly, I believe it should be at the start.  V * (t * r * s).

The following link on gamedev stackexchange goes into this. [matrix order](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16719/what-is-the-correct-order-to-multiply-scale-rotation-and-translation-matrices-f)

Also, your project takes in a Vector3 that has been already multiplied into wvp matrix, I dont see you have multiplied it in your convert_3dto2d function.

Basically, execute a TRS matrix multiply on your original vert, then multiply your WVP matrix then execute your project.  You will then get your screen space pixel.